# How to export a symbol from a Rust executable?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to export a symbol from a Rust executable:

```
#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
#[no_mangle]
pub static exported_symbol: [u8; 1] = *b"\0";

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

`exported_symbol` doesn't appear to be exported by the resulting binary:

```
$ cargo build
$ nm ./target/debug/test_export| grep exported_symbol
```

On the other hand, if I build a library with the same source, the symbol does get exported:

```
$ rustc --crate-type cdylib src/main.rs
$ nm libmain.so| grep exported_symbol
0000000000016c10 R exported_symbol
```

I'm using Rust 1.18.0 on Linux x86-64.

Comment: Why would an *executable* want to export a symbol?

Comment: I want it to emulate an existing C binary that loads plugins, and part of the interface is that the binary makes symbols available to the plugin.

Comment: Rust 1.17 is the current stable version, you should probably include the beta / nightly date and git hash if you are using 1.18.

Comment: @Shepmaster A real use case for this is communicating the GPU preference in hybrid systems. Both AMD and NVIDIA systems favor the low-power GPU unless the executable explicitly requests a high-performance GPU. That preference is communicated through exported symbols (`AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` and `NvOptimusEnablement`, respectively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend this in the `.cargo/config` file instead of the above:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=-rdynamic"]
```

`-rdynamic` is more portable. In particular, it works both on Linux and MacOS.

Also, in current Rust/LLVM versions, unless a symbol is actually used, the linker is very likely to remove it.

In order to avoid this, a dummy function referencing the exported functions should be called (at any point in time, such as in the `main` function).

An example of such a function could be:

```rust
pub fn init() {
    let funcs: &[*const extern "C" fn()] = &[
        exported_function_1 as _,
        exported_function_2 as _,
        exported_function_3 as _      
    ];
    std::mem::forget(funcs);
}
```

And of course, the exported functions should have the `#[no_mangle]` property:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn exported_function_1() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: On macOS I had to use `std::hint::black_box` in my init function to convince the linker to keep the symbol:
`pub fn init() {    let funcs: &[extern "C" fn()] = &[my_fn];    std::mem::forget(std::hint::black_box(my_fn)); }
`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass linker options to rustc, like:

```
$ rustc src/main.rs --crate-type bin -C link-args=-Wl,-export-dynamic
$ nm main|grep export
00000000000d79c4 R exported_symbol
```

You'll probably want to put this in your rustflags in your [.cargo/config](http://doc.crates.io/config.html) something like:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = [ "-C", "link-args=-Wl,-export-dynamic" ]
```

Comment: `cargo rustc` is also available.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is there a way to record this in Cargo.toml, by any chance?

Comment: Now I'm curious: why doesn't Rust export those symbols by default? Could you elaborate on that? :)

Comment: There may be a performance impact or other problems when exporting symbols https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2008/02/why-would-an-executable-export-symbols/