# Export function from Rust Windows binary crate

Tags: windows, rust, ffi

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn migrate(hdl: *mut usize, err: &mut MaybeUninit<usize>) {
  // ...
}
```

I am trying to export the above function in a `bin` crate on Windows 64-bit. The output of `rustup show` is as below:

```
nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.51.0-nightly (a2f8f6281 2021-01-27)
```

I am unable to find the symbol in the built binary (exe). Is there any way to enforce that the symbol gets export in a .exe?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, since unused symbols are probably thrown away by the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: @cer The linker cannot determine whether a **public** symbol is unused.

Comment: If we are building an executable (and not a library), won't it just assume that everything non-reachable from the entry point is unused?

Comment: Even if I use the symbol, it doesn't get exported. Output of `link /dump /symbols target/debug/engine.exe` only shows the sections.

Comment: @cer Assuming this is using Microsoft's linker, then a public symbol isn't ever pruned, regardless of whether this ends up in an .exe or .dll.

Comment: @eni Shouldn't you be using [`/EXPORTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dash-exports) rather than [`/SYMBOLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/symbols)?

Comment: @IInspectable ah yes, my mistake. But no, same problem is there.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to [implement workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43712979/1889329) to work around the workarounds introduced to deal with ELF's unfortunate decision to make everything public by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have a weird workaround: produce a .dll as well as the .exe

In `cargo.toml`, we define the current crate to output a lib as well, produced from `exports.rs`

```
[lib]
name = "exports"
path = "src/exports.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

In `exports.rs`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn migrate(hdl: *mut usize, err: &mut MaybeUninit<usize>) {
  // ...
}
```

When building, the target directory as these artifacts:
`engine.exe`
`exports.dll`

and the symbols are present in exports.dll